# How temporary objects get avoided by using c++ templates when doing additions?

Tags: c++, templates, temporary-objects

I am reading an [article](http://www.flipcode.com/archives/Faster_Vector_Math_Using_Templates.shtml) by Tomas Arce. 
The article talks about improving vector addition performance by using templates. But some parts I can not follow.

The author says the following code can avoid generating temporary objects when evaluating 
`vA = vB + vC + vD`, but how? I did't get how the temporary objects get avoided. Is there someone who can explain the inside mechanism that how temporary objects get avoided when using templates.

```
template< class ta_a >
class vecarg
{
const ta_a& Argv;
public:
inline vecarg( const ta_a& A ) : Argv( A ) {}
inline const float Evaluate( const int i ) const 
{ return Argv.Evaluate( i ); }
};


template<> 
class vecarg< const float >
{
  const ta_a& Argv;
  public:
  inline vecarg( const ta_a& A ) : Argv( A ) {}
  inline const float Evaluate( const int i ) const { return Argv; }
};


template<> 
class vecarg< const int >
{
  const ta_a& Argv;
  public:
  inline vecarg( const ta_a& A ) : Argv( A ) {}
  inline const float Evaluate( const int i ) const { return (float)Argv; }
};


template< class ta_a, class ta_b, class ta_eval >
class vecexp_2
{
  const vecarg<ta_a>   Arg1;
  const vecarg<ta_b>   Arg2;


  public:
  inline vecexp_2( const ta_a& A1, const ta_b& A2 )
 : Arg1( A1 ), Arg2( A2 ) {}
  inline const float Evaluate ( const int I ) const
  { return ta_eval::Evaluate( i, Arg1, Arg2 ); }
 };

 // Listing 5
```

P.S. In the second link provided by @Severin Pappadeux, the explanation is easy to follow. Basically, all expression templates does is that: by overloading operator `+` it doesn't even perform addition instead it creates a lightweight object whose main job is holding two references to the two operands on each side of the operator `+`, and the addition is done when the operator `=` is being evaluated. By overloading the operator `+` second time (since left hand side is the lightweight object and the right hand side is `vD`), the references to the lightweight object (which holds two previous references to `vB` and `vC`) and `vD` can be created, and again the addition is done when evaluating the operator `=`.

Comment: Where's the code `vA = vB + vC + vD`?

Comment: Can you make your code sample a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) please. In it's actual form, your [code sample](http://ideone.com/RVn1Qc) doesn't fit well.

Comment: This is just a small part of a huge article (which OP linked), there is no MCVE

Comment: There is no code `vA = vB + vC + vD`, the author is just explaining. But at the end of that article, there is code which can be downloaded.

Comment: _"there is no MCVE"_ One can and should and must be constructed for a Stack Overflow question. When that article vanishes, this question is rendered totally useless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Technique is called "expression templates", there are several papers by its inventor Todd Veldhuizen,
starting with

http://ubietylab.net/ubigraph/content/Papers/pdf/ExpressionTemplates.pdf

and

http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/expression-templates/184401656

and finally Todd report

http://www.cs.indiana.edu/pub/techreports/TR542.pdf

Comment: The explanation from the second link is quite easy to understand. I will put my understanding in the main question.

Answer (score 2):

Take that article with a grain of salt the size of Detroit. It's 14 years old and optimizers have improved dramatically since then. In short, the guy is using templates to make a complex web of methods that turn A = B + C + D from:

```
    // Taking liberties with pseudocode and notation for clarity. This is
    // a very rough oversimplification
    // Create a new, wasteful, vector to store a temporary result
    vector tmp(C.x + D.x, C.y + D.y, C.z + D.z)
    // Create another new, wasteful, vector to store a temporary result:
    vector tmp2(B.x + tmp.x, B.y + tmp.y, B.z + tmp.z)
    // Waste even more time copying the result.
    A.x = tmp2.x; A.y = tmp2.y; A.z = tmp2.z;
    // In reality, your optimized compiler isn't even remotely this stupid.
```

And he is using the template preprocessor to eliminate the creation of the temporaries and the final copy. He's trying to get to the point of executing something like this:

```
    A.x = B.x + (C.x + D.x);
    A.y = B.y + (C.y + D.y);
    A.z = B.z + (C.z + D.z);
```

Remember, if you put something like this in production code that other engineers have to read, you'd damn well better have a very good reason. As in, you're going to have to demonstrate that the use of this gibberish produces a mission-critical improvement in performance. Why? Because the cost of maintaining such insanity is not negligible. Before you use anything like this, get performance numbers.

Comment: as @Severin mentioned, this is something like expression templates. But according to your consideration, is this technique still being used?

Comment: @user2345484 Yes, it is being used. Look at modern C++ linear algebra Armadillo, http://arma.sourceforge.net/, it is used in statistics, in R, ...

Answer (score 0):

The whole concept relies on storing references to native types, or evaluating expressions that fold up to native types.

There are temporary objects taking part along the way, but all they store is references to source and destination data that get resolved at some point. Compiling without optimizations may indeed allocate space, but if optimizations are enabled, the optimizer will notice there is no reason for that.

That is, if this gets compiled for CPUs that use registers. A stack-based machine may behave differently, since operations still need their operands o be pushed and popped.